# Need help editing and understanding jQuery portfolio template for Dribbble API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help understanding what the below does:

```
var inner = ""; 
var innerP1 = '<li style="list-style-type:none;"><div class="dribbble"><div class="shot"><a href="';
var innerP2 = '"><img src="';
var innerP3 = '"></a></div><div class="likes">'  
var innerP4 = ' Likes</div><div class="comments">'
var innerP5 = ' Comments</div><div class="name">'
var innerp6 = '</div></div></li>'

function render(filter){
for (var i = 0; i<filter.shots.length;i++){
inner = inner + innerP1 + filter.shots[i].url + innerP2 + filter.shots[i].image_url + innerP3 + filter.shots[i].likes_count + innerP4 + filter.shots[i].comments_count + innerP5 + filter.shots[i].title + innerp6;
};
```

I want to remove some of the field here; all i really want is the image with the link and title. What do the "var" functions do and can't I just combine all the html into one of them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `filter.shots`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Here is how I changed it:

```
var inner = ""; 
var innerP1 = '<li style="list-style-type:none;"><div class="dribbble"><div class="shot"><a href="';
var innerP2 = '"><img src="';
var innerP3 = '"></a>'  
var innerp4 = '</div></div></li>'


function render(filter){
for (var i = 0; i<filter.shots.length;i++){
inner = inner + innerP1 + filter.shots[i].url + innerP2 +         filter.shots[i].image_url + innerP3 + innerp4;
```

I realized this is a sequence where the var are variables in the sequence and the inner=... is where the order of the sequence is defined.